# Working of vnodes in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Can someone explain the working of vnodes allocation in Cassandra?
If we have a cluster of N nodes and a new node is added how are token ranges allocated to this new node?

Answer (score 2):

Rebalancing a cluster is automatically accomplished when adding or removing nodes. When a node joins the cluster, it assumes responsibility for an even portion of data from the other nodes in the cluster. If a node fails, the load is spread evenly across other nodes in the cluster.

Here is some reading that might help you better understand how vnodes work and how ranges are being allocated - [Virtual nodes in Cassandra 1.2](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/virtual-nodes-in-cassandra-1-2)

As I said above, Cassandra automatically handles the calculation of token ranges for each node in the cluster in proportion to their num_tokens value. Token assignments for vnodes are calculated by the org.apache.cassandra.dht.tokenallocator.ReplicationAwareTokenAllocator class.

When a new node joins the cluster, it will inject it's own ranges and steal some rages from the existing nodes. Also this [video](https://youtu.be/SLuMB1I3qOU?t=2814) might help